# AWS Step Functions - How to elegantly append multiple results into an existing Json path

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I've got a Pass state in Step Functions that needs to add result values into an existing input path `$.event`. I have the following definition:

```
"PrepareMessageState": {
  "Type": "Pass",
  "Parameters": {
    "transformId.$": "$.event.eventId",
    "taskRunState.$": "$.taskResult.JobRunState",
    "taskRunId.$": "$.taskResult.Id"
  },
  "ResultPath": "$.event",
  "Next": "PublishMessageTask"
},
```

**Desired output**

I can't share the exact shape of the input message `$.event`, but it has lots of other fields. I want to append the three results above directly to `$.event`, so that we get

```
"event": {
    // other fields
    "transformId": "1234567",
    "taskRunState": "SUCCEEDED",
    "taskRunId": "abcdefg"
}
```

**What I'm actually getting**

The state machine with the definition above just returns this instead:

```
"event": {
    "transformId": "1234567",
    "taskRunState": "SUCCEEDED",
    "taskRunId": "abcdefg"
}
```

The problem is that the rest of the `$.event` message is being overwritten.

The docs online seem only to show how to append a single key-value pair: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-resultpath.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the new [`States.JsonMerge` Intrinsic Function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html#asl-intrsc-func-json-manipulate)

Comment: Can you show how to use `States.JsonMerge()` to produce the desired output?

Comment: Here is a sample from a different answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75832309/2193968  States.JsonMerge($, `States.StringsToJson(States.Format('\\{\"{}\": \"{}\"\\}', $.key2, $.value3)), false)
`